# Not using useEffect dependencies causing state to not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question about `useEffect` and `useCallback`.

I have react code that will request and load data when you scroll to the bottom of the screen.

```js
export default function ImagePage() {
  const [artData, setArtData] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(2)

  const url = "https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks?page=1&limit=5"

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => { // <---CALLBACK HERE
    if (isLoading) return

    setIsLoading(true)

    axios.get(`https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks?page=${index}&limit=5`)
      .then((res) => {
        setArtData(((prevItems) => [... new Set ([...prevItems, ...res.data.data])]))
        setIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1) <---CHANGING INDEX 
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
  }, [index, isLoading])

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    axios.get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setArtData(res.data.data)
        setIsLoading(false)
        console.log("use effect loaded")
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => { // <---USE EFFECT IN QUESTION
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const {scrollTop, clientHeight, scrollHeight} = document.querySelector('#image-page-container')
      if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - clientHeight) {
        console.log("Fetching data")
        console.log(index)
        fetchData()
      }
    }

    document.querySelector('#image-page-container').addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)

    return () => {
      document.querySelector('#image-page-container').removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
      }
    }, [fetchData]) <--- If i remove "fetchData" the state "index" won't get updated
```

My question is:

As you see at the bottom of the code, the final `useEffect()` is using the `fetchData` callback as a dependency. If I remove the dependency, the code works fine however the `index` state does not get updated.

Can anyone shed light of this curious occurrence?

**What I know**
I know the `useEffect` dependencies are used to decided when the effect is run (if state of dependency changes). However I'm not yet sure how a *callBack* can change states. This hole in my knowledge may be where the answer to the strange reaction is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove `fetchData` as an external dependency from the last `useEffect` hook, you are closing over the "instance" of `fetchData` from the initial render cycle where `index` had a value of `2`.

Without the `fetchData` dependency, then `handleScroll` gets a "copy" of that initial `fetchData` function then `handleScroll` is passed as a scroll event listener. The `index` value closed over in `fetchData` is used in the URL of the Axios GET request and it never sees any updated value.

By including the re-memoized `fetchData` (*from the `useCallback` hook*) in the dependency array, the `useEffect` hook properly cleans up the previous `handleScroll` "instance" that was used as a scroll event handler and the new "instance" of `handleScroll` gets the new "instance" of `fetchData` which has the updated `index` state value closed over in callback scope.